# Multiple Droplist Filters in 1 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has 1 filter that on change filters the view. My question is how do I add a second droplist and a third. I am not sure how to start this process. Here is what I am currently doing with 1.

```
    Branch: @Html.DropDownList("Branch", ViewBag.Branches as SelectList, "All Locations")
```

```
    $("#Branch").change(function () {
        var deptId = $(this).val();
        var routeVal = "?Branch=";
        var url = '@Url.Action("Branch", "Employees")';
        var link = url + routeVal + deptId
        window.location.href = link });
```

And in my controller:
        public ActionResult Branch(string Branch)
        {
            ViewBag.BranchName = Branch;

```
        IEnumerable<Employee> employees = from m in db.Employees
                                          where m.Branch == Branch || Branch == null || Branch == ""
                                          select m;
        IEnumerable<Branch> branches = from c in bCon.Branches
                                         where c.BranchName == Branch
                                         select c;

        var viewModel = new BranchViewModel()
        {
            BranchName = Branch,
            Employees = employees.ToList(),
            Branches = branches.ToList()
        };

        return View(viewModel);

    }
```

Regards,
SEB

Answer (score 0):

you send viewModel to View just use @Model in razor.

```
Branch: @Html.DropDownList("Branch", @Model.Branches as SelectList, "All Locations")
Employees : @Html.DropDownList("Branch", @Model.Employees as SelectList, "All Locations")
```